# Error while trying to rebuild the solution of windows forms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio, msbuild

Everytime I open the database from visual studio 2017 and then try to rebuild the solution of windows form I get those errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB3021 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\bsuro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\App_Data\Database.mdf" to "bin\Debug\App_Data\Database.mdf". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\bsuro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\App_Data\Database.mdf' because it is being used by another process.     C:\Users\bsuro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2.csproj  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4353
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\bsuro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\App_Data\Database.mdf" to "bin\Debug\App_Data\Database.mdf". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.     C:\Users\bsuro\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2.csproj  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4353

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this happen if you close and reopen visual studio? Does it happen if you run visual studio as administrator? Also - try opening your task manager and look for a process of your application, it might be running in the background.

Comment: When I re-open visual everything is working again, but as soon as I open again my database the problem repeats herself.. I tried to look out for my application in the task manager with no success

Comment: *"As soon as I open again my database the problem repeats herself"* - Do not open your database while trying to build - you are locking the `mdf` file. See my updated answer.

Comment: Not while building. I open my database and then try to rebuild and there is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because another process is using your project's resources, or you have insufficiant privilages to modify them.

Try the following actions:

- *"As soon as I open again my database the problem repeats herself"* - Do not open your database while trying to build - you are locking the `mdf` file.
- Open your task manager and look for a process of your application, it might be running in the background. If it does, kill it.
- Make sure you are building in "Debug" mode and not in "Release" mode. If you are, there could be a production EXE running somewhere.
- Close and reopen Visual Studio.
- Start Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: when I re-open visual everything is working again.. but as soon as I open again my database the problem pops up again.. I can't re-open my visual every 3 minutes :/
I will try to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

well what you have to do is on the top of vs, there is a button debug and kind of on the bottom a menu debug, now it has to be set on debug and next to it there is another menu, you have to set that to x86 click on it go to config settings than add x86 than run and all should be good